# How do I set my development web browser in VS2010 RC?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, browser, settings

I don't like to use IE for my system default web browser.

*but*

I do want to set IE as my browser in VS2010 because it works a little nicer for debugging and I like to develop to the lowest common denominator. (jab, lol)... anyhow, can I default to debugging against IE?

I know in VS2008 you just had to "Browse With..." on an .aspx page. But that option doesn't exist in **VS2010 RC**.  What gives?

Comment: seriously, i second this, what gives?  why completely remove that option away?  my default browser is chrome, but i want my asp web apps to be launched in firefox via the IDE.  it worked well in vs2008.  *sniff*

Comment: Protected this question because of frequent new users leaving comments as answers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is for VS2008, but should apply just as well to VS2010.

You have several options.

Go to the web project properties to the "web" tab.

Option 1:

- Under "Start Action", select "Start External Program" and set the path to your browser of choice, pass the URL in through the command line parameters

Option 2:

- Setup your machine to use your browser of choice as the default browser.
- Under "Start Action", select "Start URL". This will invoke the default browser.

Comment: Oh god! That's a terrible step backwards. heh. Oh well. Microsoft is as Microsoft does.

Got it working... +1 thanks.

Comment: Excellent adivce as I can now control which browser specific web projects will open to debug!

Answer (score 33):

The solution really is not that difficult, though it is not as direct as it ought to be...

In Visual Studio 2010, the Browse With option **is** available. However, it **is not** available for MVC Views!

Simply add a Web Form or HTML Page to your project, and Browse With is readily available in it's context menu. Here you can set the Default Browser, and that setting will be used for all subsequent debugging.

Comment: (+1) This worked for me in an MVC project.  Thanks.  Added an aspx page, did the "Browse with / set default" trick, then deleted the aspx page.

Comment: +1 this did the trick. there really should be a Browse with option for MVC views...

Comment: Also - like some other things - the "Browse with" option isn't available while your debugging

Answer (score 10):

The "World of VS Default Browser Switcher" vs2010 extension will select your desired browser for you and it works with MVC too. This is a free extension :)

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921

It was originally built based on a post by Scott Hanselman
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToChangeTheDefaultBrowserInVisualStudioProgrammaticallyWithPowerShellAndPossiblyPokeYourselfInTheEye.aspx

Comment: Too bad you have to reinstall it every day.

Comment: BTW, there is a built-in browser switcher for VS2012. And I agree with Ronnie, the extension I mentioned above does require uninstalling and re-installing every now and then.

Answer (score 7):

"Browse With..." only appears in VS2010 (aspx page context menu) when you already have IE set as the default browser for everything (system).  It's there to let you select an alternate browser to IE.

This is a big #fail in my opinion. I've had moderate success with thtese steps.

1. Set IE as default system browser
2. Open VS2010.
3. Set IE as default browser using "Browse With"
4. Change your default system browser back to your preferred choice (while VS2010 is still open)

I say moderate results because the settings don't seem to persist or aer randomly persisted at best.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why "Browse with..." does not always appear in context menu.

Answer (score 4):

"Browse With..." Will not show up when you are in debug mode, FYI.  That's probably why you think it's missing.

Answer (score 4):

right click on the project .
Then add-> new item -> HTML Page

A "HTMLPage1.htm" will be added to the project. 
"Browse With ..." exists in its context menu. Use its Browse With menu then delete the file after done.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just found you can do this in VS2010.

Right click the Web Project and go to 'Browse With' - Set the default browser in here.

Comment: Yeah, that only works in VS2008. I actually knew about that one, as I mentioned in the question. In VS2010, however, I don't see that option when I right click an .aspx file in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

No, Tim is right.  The 'Browse With' option DOES show in VS2010 - at least in VS2010 Pro.

Comment: Well it didn't exist in the RC... which was what my question was about.

Comment: I'm using VS2010 Pro here at work, and I had to add the "phoney" HTML page to get the "Browse With" menu item, as mentioned above and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Browse With' option does exist. But it is shown in context menu of a file\folder and not in a context menu of whole web application.

You may setup default browser there.

Answer (score -1):

Yes Tim and Monsingor is Right go to SubFcontext menu of a file\folder and right click and set default Browser
sadhana