# Change default browser in Visual Studio 2010 RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, browser, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 (RC) there is no longer a "browse with" context menu when right clicking .aspx pages. How can you change the default browser now?

By default it seems to use the operating system default browser, but I would prefer to use IE when debugging ASP.net apps. (I am testing this with ASP.net MVC 2)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no "Browse With" option on the .aspx Views in an MVC project as they are not meant to be directly browseable.

What I tend to do is add a Default.aspx webform in the root of the site and this, when right clicked, will give you the Browse With option. You need to make sure to update your routing though otherwise IIS/Cassini will try to serve it up, something like this

```
   public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        // Change the current path so that the Routing handler can correctly interpret
        // the request, then restore the original path so that the OutputCache module
        // can correctly process the response (if caching is enabled).

        string originalPath = Request.Path;
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
        IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
        httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, false);
    }
```

Also, another quicky is to hit CTRL-F5 (run without debugging) which will fire up the site without going into debug mode..

Comment: Thanks so much.  silverlight didn't debug right in any browser but IE, and now I can set my windows default to a browser that I like!

Comment: After adding the Default.aspx page and setting the default browser to whatever you want on the "Browser with" menu, you can then simply delete the Default.aspx page.  VS2010 will remember your choice.

Answer (score 16):

this is the only working way for me: 
[How do I set my development web browser in VS2010 RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364723/how-do-i-set-my-development-web-browser-in-vs2010-rc/3108691#3108691)

There is also a **browser switcher extension** for Visual Studio, which works perfectly!
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921
[image: Browser Switcher]

**update:**
the extension is removed from the gallery, try this one:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/233945ae-0b7b-47e7-9b02-c5a11798afb5

[image: Default Browser Changer]

Comment: This is no longer available, which is unfortunate, because it was a great extension

Comment: Maybe this one does the job too: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/233945ae-0b7b-47e7-9b02-c5a11798afb5

Answer (score 15):

this [browser switching extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921) is what i use. It's pretty awesome.

**EDIT**: [`Possible new link`](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/233945ae-0b7b-47e7-9b02-c5a11798afb5)

Answer (score 10):

I just added a **.htm** page and right clicked on it. There I had **Browse With...**

Answer (score 4):

The solution really is not that difficult, though it is not as direct as it ought to be...

In Visual Studio 2010, the Browse With option **is** available. However, it **is not** available for MVC Views!

Simply add a Web Form or HTML Page to your project, and Browse With is readily available in it's context menu. Here you can set the Default Browser, and that setting will be used for all subsequent debugging.

No need for complicated code in an Default.aspx page, or changing the Windows defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is going to be in a future release.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533930/default-browser-setting-in-vs2010-not-per-project-helps-debug-user-experience

btw, you can change your default browser:-
In WindowsXP atleast..
Go to Start > Control Panel > Add and Remove progam> Set Program access and defaults > Choose IE from the Web browser dropdown.

**Edited:**
btw, I did see the "Browse with" item in the right click of an aspx page. When I click on that, I see the list of broswers to choose from. You select one an click "Set as default".

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

[How do I set my development web browser in VS2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364723/how-do-i-set-my-development-web-browser-in-vs2010)

I'm using VS 2010 RC and I can't see the "Browse with..." option too.

Answer (score 2):

"Browse With.." is available on VS2010. 
Left Click the empty space of top panel -> select "Web Browser".
Right click .aspx, "Browse With.." is accessible now.

Answer (score 1):

Go to :

```
C:\Users\[Your current user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\browsers.xml
```

clear all contents and save 
------if your default browser at the windows is IE new settings change to IE -----
Compile your application

Comment: This does not help to change debug browser

Answer (score 0):

another way (and more easy) that we can do this is:
open the browser that you want, for example, IE and going in 
Tools > Options > Programs > and click the button like "Set Default Browser"

Comment: Sadly VS2010 has a habbit of "losing" this setting from time to time, everyday I have to reset mine to use IE instead of FF. (The browser extension is by far the best and quickest way to swap over)