# Internet Explorer events not working

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-9, watin

I am trying to run tests using [WatiN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir#Similar_tools) with Internet Explorer 9, and my environment won't activate events like `keyup`, `onkeydown`, ect. This keeps causing tests to fail. When on other machines they succeed.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried any of the ie-js variants? http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Internet Explorer is not set as your default browser / start browser, this can prevent the events being captured correctly.

Have you checked the document engine, etc. being used to render in Internet Explorer? (press <kbd>F12</kbd>)

P.S.: See Stack Overflow question *[Change default browser in Visual Studio 2010 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443749/change-default-browser-in-visual-studio-2010-rc)* for some browser switching extensions for Visual Studio

Comment: I do have IE 9 set as the default, The document engine being used is the IE 9 standards. Also when a test does rarely manage to finish, the browser.close() takes over a minute or two too close the browser, we have a lot of tests and this might br related.

Comment: Just noticed some test's document type is quirks would that change how the events work?

Comment: It will most likely influence results, and possibly cause test failures depending upon what exactly you are doing in your app... P.S. There was recently a watin fix for FireFox which was not passing event params... worth looking into to see if the same is happening for your IE9

Comment: The problem has been solved, I had to revert to IE8 and I also needed to activate protected mode in the security options. thank your for your help!