# Visual Studio 2012 Website Does Work Properly in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I originally created an ASP.NET site in Visual Studio 2010 a few years ago and it went through the VS 2010 SP1 update as well.  This meant that Visual Studio 2012 opened the solution without performing a one time upgrade.

The issue I am having is that the built-in browser selector in Visual Studio 2012 is not available for this project and the settings only let you use the default browser.

When I looked in the .SLN file, the version line indicates Visual Studio 2012 (i.e. # Visual Studio 2012) and no other setting in there appears to have anything to do with this limitation.

Has anybody had this issue and, if so, can you please let me know how your overcame it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to upgrade your project to allow it to make use of Visual Studio 2012 only features. Note, if you do this you will no longer be able to open your project in earlier versions of VS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747%28VS.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  Ended up being the first important part of the solution.  After the upgrade, I then had to remove both SUO files and then rebuild the solution.  Then when I set the web project in the solution to the default startup project the browser selector started to work once again.

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2010 , you can install [WoVS Default Browser Switcher](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921) extension

Also a related question [Change default browser in Visual Studio 2010 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443749/change-default-browser-in-visual-studio-2010-rc)