# How to change the default browser for debug in MVC 4 application in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, debugging, browser, visual-studio-debugging

I want to change my default browser when debugging a MVC 4 application but it always starts the IE. When I copy/paste the  URL to the other browser(Firefox) it works but it doesn't hit the breakpoints. I tried by adding a 'Default.htm' page in the Views folder and tried to change the 'Browse with..' option but it was not there at all(the browse with option). Do you know How can I achieve it ?

**EDIT**

I am using visual studio 2010

**Solution for me:**

The way I did it was to change the default browser in the "Program defaults" and then it started to hit the breakpoints after debug with copy/paste of the url from the IE.

Comment: what VS do you use? Try this article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToChangeTheDefaultBrowserInVisualStudioProgrammaticallyWithPowerShellAndPossiblyPokeYourselfInTheEye.aspx

Comment: @freshbm it is Visual Studio 2010

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443749/change-default-browser-in-visual-studio-2010-rc ` is going to help I guess and this makes it a duplicate as well!

Comment: Well, it didn't work for me. But the way I did it was to change the default browser in the "Program defaults" and then it started to hit the breakpoints after debug with copy/paste of the url from the IE.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik always tag the `user` you are communicating to, otherwise the user remains `unaware` of your response. Good, if its working for you now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its in the Run button dropdown. all installed browsers list will be there set ur default browser. By default it will be Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

In VS, in top bar, click right menu, select `Standart` toolbar options and add `Debug Target` there

Comment: There is no Debug Target option

Answer (score 0):

Right click the web page you want to open, choose "Browse with...", select your desired browser, click "Set as default".