# Prevent visual studio 2010 start a local IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, iis-express

I have a solution with many types of projects, and some of them are websites. Usually, I debug a non-website projects, but everytime I start to debug any project in the solution, the local visual studio IIS starts runnning.

Is there any possible way to stop running the IIS server ???

Thanks!

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364723/how-do-i-set-my-development-web-browser-in-vs2010-rc.  I *think* there's a "no browser" option.  I think.

Comment: Hey @RussellUhl. Thanks for the reference, but it doesn't answer the question....
Besides, the no browser option does not start a browser, while I don't even want the web server to start.

Comment: ohhhhhhh.  I misunderstood.  In that case, I can't help you, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Open your project and go to the projects Properties.  In web apps, you should see a Web tab/choice.  Click that, then you can configure which/what server you want to start.  I think that the default is that VStudio likes to use it's internal IIS Express, but you can configure it to use IIS locally on the box or to use a custom server.

You can actually set the project to not start anything in the Start Action section on that 'tab' as well, and to simply wait until it registers a connection.

Note that if you are trying to debug using a non-local server, then remote debugging will have to be on on the server, which isn't a great idea in production environments.

Comment: Hey @ShawnW., in the "start action" section I can choose "not to open a page", but it still runs the IIS-express.

Comment: beneath that should be a section called 'Servers', that's the section ShawnW is talking about.

Comment: Correct Mike C.  Under the Start action section is the section where you can disable IIS from starting, or otherwise configure it to what you need.  Thanks for the catch there.